# Python package import disables logging

Tags: python, logging, shapely

Why does this work (i.e. log message appear):

```
import logging as log
log.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s (%(funcName)s): %(message)s',
                level=log.INFO)
from shapely.geometry import Point
log.info("test")

> INFO (<module>): test
```

and this not (i.e. log messages do not appear):

```
import logging as log
from shapely.geometry import Point
log.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s (%(funcName)s): %(message)s',
                level=log.INFO)
log.info("test")
```

Am I doing something wrong or could this be a bug in the `shapely` package / function?

Comment: This was fixed only a day before this question; see [PR #313](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/pull/313).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `shapely` module is using `logging` to output warnings and debugging messages *at import time*. The logging module *autoconfigures* when you first try to log a message to it and it hasn't yet been configured. So importing `shapely` has the side effect of configuring `logging` if it has not yet been configured.

Once configured, `basicConfig` has no effect unless you reset the configuration. You can do so by clearing the root logger handlers:

```
import logging
del logging.getLogger().handlers[:]
```

but you'd be better of configuring logging *before* importing `shapely`.

Comment: Also, [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) states that:

    Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.
    
    Imports should be grouped in the following order:

        standard library imports
        related third party imports
        local application/library specific imports

Comment: Great - thanks! So is it bad practice what `shapely` is doing (i.e. should I open an issue on GitHub) in your opinion? I have too little experience to tell.

Comment: @hd1 Thanks! Does this include configuration of the packages being imported? So in this case would I `import logging`, then `logging.basicConfig` and then `import shapely`, right?

Comment: No @n1000, the standard is linked from my comment.

Comment: @hd1 Then I don't get your comment. The order of imports is respected in my second example, but it does not work. Are you saying this part of the answer is "bad style": _but you'd be better of configuring logging before importing `shapely`._?

Comment: If you choose to follow pep8, then you shouldn't configure before importing.

Comment: @hd1: PEP8 is also a *guideline*. Following PEP8 does not require you to implement those guidelines religiously. If a `basicConfig` call solves a practical issue, then it is *fine* to insert that before an import. Just add a comment explaining why you did so.

Comment: @n1000: They are using `logging` to communicate on import issues; I wouldn't call it 'bad practice', per se. But it may be something they want to document explicitly.